# Refresh sysdepends for a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

I have tables in a merge-replicated database that don't show any entries in `sysdepends` (both at the publisher and subscriber and event on my empty testing development database). This means that the merge agent has to re-try a lot of operations as foreign keys don't exist when it tries to process the row.

Even if I add a foreign key to or from the tables, no new rows are added to `sysdepends`.

Is there any way to force sysdepends to update for a table? I know you can use `sp_refreshsqlmodule` to force code to refresh, but that won't work in this case.

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. A coworker with SQL 2012 is showing the same thing on *some* of her databases.

Answer (score 0):

sysdepends is deprecated

You should be using sys.sql_dependencies

Comment: I didn't have a vote in the processing logic for SQL Server Merge Replication.

Comment: Who down-voted this?  This is a valid answer. I've found sysdepends VERY unreliable in tracking dependencies, but sys.sql_dependencies works great for me.

Comment: I agree that it's unreliable, but my question is specifically how to get sysdepends working correctly for the built-in SQL Server Merge Replication. That it's not the best dependency manager for SQL Server is known, but your answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Then your question wasn't clear, because what I read was "how do I get valid system dependencies".  And you can't via sysdepends.  Full stop.  So.... the correct answer is to use sys.sql_dependencies.  I'm sorry you don't like the answer. But that doesn't mean it deserves a downvote and it doesn't mean I didn't answer your question as I read it.